# Best Way to Convert ArrayList to String in Kotlin

Tags: android, string, arraylist, kotlin

I have an ArrayList of String in kotlin

```
private val list = ArrayList<String>()
```

I want to convert it into `String` with a separator ",". I know we can do it programatically through loop but in other languages we have mapping functions available like in java we have

```
StringUtils.join(list);
```

And in Swift we have

```
array.joined(separator:",");
```

Is there any method available to convert `ArrayList` to `String` with
 a separator in Kotlin?

And what about for adding custom separator like "-" etc?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Kotlin has [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) method just for this

```
list.joinToString()
```

You can change a separator like this

```
list.joinToString(separator = ":")
```

If you want to customize it more, these are all parameters you can use in this function

```
val list = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
println(
    list.joinToString(
        prefix = "[",
        separator = ":",
        postfix = "]",
        limit = 3,
        truncated = "...",
        transform = { it.uppercase() }
    )
)
```

which outputs

> [ONE:TWO:THREE:...]

Comment: what about adding own separator?

Comment: Hi, can anyone help me out. When my arraylist size is one, joinToString produce ","?

Answer (score 12):

Kotlin as well has method for that, its called `joinToString`.

You can simply call it like this:

`list.joinToString());`

Because by default it uses comma as separator but you can also pass your own separator as parameter, this method takes quite a few parameters aside from separator, which allow to do a lot of formatting, like prefix, postfix and more.

You can read all about it [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html)

Comment: what about adding own separator?

Comment: You can for sure
joinToString(separator: CharSequence = ", ", prefix: CharSequence = "", postfix: CharSequence = "", limit: Int = -1, truncated: CharSequence = "...", transform: ((T) -> CharSequence)? = null)

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin there is `reduce` function and it is same as in javascript . This function iterates all the list value and adds to previous value .

```
val listVal: List<String> = listOf("a","b","c","d")
val stringVal = listVal.reduce{ acc, s -> 
                "$acc : ${s.uppercase()}"
}
```