# Why my progam is returing totally different value instead of numeric?

Tags: kotlin, jvm, ide

```
fun digitize(n:Long):IntArray {
    return n.toString().map(Character::getNumericValue).toIntArray().reversedArray()
}
fun main(){
    println(digitize(348597)
    )
}
```

> Output: [I@4e50df2e

I'm not sure there is some issues with the IDE or my program.

Edit:

Using `.asList()` solves the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best Way to Convert ArrayList to String in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515172/best-way-to-convert-arraylist-to-string-in-kotlin)

Comment: @ofekHod Using   `.asList()` solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your digitize is returning `IntArray` which on JVM means `int[]`. Using `println` on it you get an address.

To print every member of the `IntArray` you need `contentToString` (extension) method.

```kotlin
        fun digitize(n: Long): IntArray {
            return n.toString().map(Character::getNumericValue).toIntArray().reversedArray()
        }

        println(digitize(348597).contentToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `as.List()` solves the problem.**

```
fun digitize(n:Long):IntArray {

    return n.toString().map(Character::getNumericValue).toIntArray().reversedArray()
}
fun main(){

    println(digitize(348597).asList())
}
```